# One part power series annihilator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series, algebraic-combinatorics

This following appear in infinite variable but for discussion let's take everything is finite if it makes the answer simpler.
\begin{equation} \label{PartitionfuncKS}
\mathcal{Z}^{KS}(x)=\sum_{\substack{g\geq 0, n\geq 1\\ 2g-2+n >0 }}\frac{h^{2g-2+n}}{n!}\sum_{(\alpha_1 ,\ldots , \alpha_n) \in I^{n}}F_{g,n}[\alpha_1 ,  \ldots \alpha_n ]x_{\alpha_{1}}\cdots x_{\alpha_{n}}\quad(*)
\end{equation}
The above equation is annihilated by
\begin{equation}
L_{i}:= \hbar\partial^{i}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{cd}A^{icd}x_{c}x_{d}-\sum_{cd}\hbar B_{c}^{id}\partial^{c}x_{d}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{cd}\hbar^{2}C_{cd}^{i}\partial^{c}\partial^{d}-\hbar D^{i},
\end{equation}
where $\partial^i: = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, $A,B,C,D$ are constant that is $L_i$ partial differential equation.
The following generating function
\begin{equation} 
\label{onept}
\mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x)=\sum_{\substack{g\geq 0,\\ 2g-1 >0 }}h^{2g-1}\sum_{\alpha_1  \in I}F_{g,n}[\alpha_1 ]x_{\alpha_{1}}\quad (**)
\end{equation}
can be derived from (*) from (**).
we introduce a parameter $s$ alongside $x$. Hence
$$ 
\mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\mathcal{Z}^{KS}(sx)\Bigg\lfloor_{s=0}
$$
My question is what is the corresponding operator that annihilate $\mathcal{Z}_{onept}^{KS}(x)$. How does it related to $L_i$?
Is there any literature regarding this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $s=1$ instead of $s=0$ ?

Comment: I want to extract only coefficient of s and want everything else to vanish.

Comment: As I replace x by sx and then take the expansion in s then $\sum F_g,1 [\alpha]x_{\alpha}$ is the coefficient of s.